# VBA replace range inside function formula with its calculated values

Tags: vba, excel

This is my first post here. I tried to look for an answer but could not find one.

My issue is to replace range in a formula to its specific values.
To illustrate the issue consider a cell:

**=AVERAGE(A1:A10)**

I want this cell to show the average arguments for the calculation:

**=AVERAGE({1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10})**

This thing is parallel to pressing F9 while the range A1:A10 is highlighted.
I tried to build something from what I could find in the net but could not make it working:

```
Sub ChangeFormulas()
Const CONST_FUNCTION As String = "AVERAGE"
Dim cell As Range
Dim tmp As String
Dim res As Variant

For Each cell In Selection

  With cell

    If InStr(.Formula, CONST_FUNCTION) > 0 Then

        tmp = Mid(.Formula, 10, InStr(.Formula, ")") - (InStr(.Formula, CONST_FUNCTION) + 8))

        cell.Formula = Replace(cell.Formula, tmp, Application.Evaluate(tmp))
    End If
  End With
Next cell
End Sub
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This begs the question of "Why?". Once you do this, the formulas will be static and will always equal the same value. The whole point of formulas is to allow dynamic recalculations. Also, do you just want the value of the evaluation? So for example `=AVERAGE("")` would be something like `12.345` where the former is the formula, and the latter is the value of the average? If so, just overwrite the cell value.

Comment: If you plan to pursue this, you will have to use `,` instead of `;` as a list separator or switch to .FormulaLocal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cant think why, in accordance with @Brandon Barney, but here is what you need

`"=AVERAGE({" &  join(application.transpose(range("i1:i4").Value),";") & "})"`

Which will return like so

`=AVERAGE({1;5;5;10})`

Comment: See my comment to the OP.

Comment: Thank you Nathan.
Thats what I was looking for.
The reason to do so is for presentive aspects (to see the number arguments of the calculation in a register file)

BTW @Jeeped - What is the reason of using `,` instead of `;` ?